# Open empty Sublime Text window when launching from start menu

Tags: windows-7, sublime-text-2, sublime-text

I have several Sublime Text windows open. I want to open a new empty ST window (to be more precise: with one, empty tab) by clicking on ST in the start menu. But when I click on it, an already-open ST window is brought to the front, instead of a new window.

Any solution?

Answer (score 5):

The following works for Sublime Text 3 in Windows 10. I think there's a good chance it will work for Sublime Text 2 in Windows 7 as well:

1. In the folder where the Start Menu's shortcut is located (e.g. C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Sublime Text), create a copy of the shortcut
2. Right-click on the copy, and select the "Properties" option
3. Append " -n" (without the quotes) to the value in the "Target" textbox (note the space before the hyphen)
4. Click the "OK" button
5. Rename the new shortcut to something like "Sublime Text 3 (New Instance)"

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Please accept this answer!

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

With Sumlime already open, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open a new window.

Worked for me running ST2 on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to first focus a Sublime window, though. Often I don't have any Sublime windows open on my current virtual desktop (I use virtual desktops via a third party app).

Comment: If you are okay with Sublime not remembering your previously opened files, you could change `"remember_open_files":` in your User Preferences to `false`. I believe you will also need to alter `"hot_exit":` to `false` for that to have any effect in your User Prefs as well.

Comment: Well, I do want Sublime to remember my session after I've closed all of its windows and then reopened Sublime.